# Extending sink drain rough in. Legal? Correct?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, vanity

[image: Current bathroom plumbing on left, what I need on the right]

My Wife bought a new Vanity (and her husband forgot to look at all the details.. :) ) and the specific dimensions require that the drain / water lines be roughed in around 22 IN. Our current setup is 16 1/2.

My question is could I just put a 90 degree elbow on the current drain, then add an extension pipe to get me to 22 inches in height? (Not sure if this is legal, or would actually work appropriately with a p trap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the 22 inches would just be a maximum height you could have it in order to achieve the  proper slope for drainage.  It is not uncommon to plumb sinks into drains that are less than 22 inches .  Just use a longer tailpiece or extension from the drain basket down to the trap and then over to the drain.  Your wife's husband can rest asured that it will be all right.